How to access associated objects in a nested form
How do I use a nested form, for an object association, but display values from both the associated object, and the object association itself?
Excerpt of the nested form:
<%= form_with model: @document, local: true, :method => :post do | document_form | %>
...
<%= document_form.fields_for :document_authors do | author_form | %>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left">
            **<%= author.fname %> <%= author.lname %>**
            <%= author_form.hidden_field :id %>
            <%= author_form.hidden_field :document_id %>
            <%= author_form.hidden_field :author_id, value: **author.id** %>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= author_form.radio_button :is_public, 'true' %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= author_form.radio_button :is_public, 'false' %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
...

Standard Document:
class Document < ActiveRecord
    has_many :document_authors
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :document_authors
end

Standard Author:
class Author < ActiveRecord
    has_many :documents, through => :document_authors
end

And standard association table:
class DocumentAuthor < ActiveRecord
    belongs_to :documents
    has_many :authors
end

Document Author Controller:
def new
    @document = Document.find( params[:id] )
    @specific_authors = Author.where( criteria )
    @specific_authors.each do | author |
        document_author = @document.document_authors.find_or_create_by( :author_id => author.id )
    end
    if @document.changed?
        @document.save  
    end
end

I had the new method add the authors first, because I was having issues with the form not showing any blank document_authors allowing authors to be added. It's a temporary work around, the accessing the author properties (fname, lname) is the more important issue.
When the form loads, the database receives a call from /views/document_authors/new.html.erb, line "3", (the fields_for line)
  DocumentAuthor Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `document_authors`.* FROM `document_authors` WHERE `document_authors`.`document_id` = 3

Results:
--------------------------------------------
| id | document_id | author_id | is_public |
--------------------------------------------
| 22 |          3  |        19 |      true |
| 23 |          3  |        32 |     false |

Previously, I had an @authors object, that it would step through each author, and then display their name.  However, when I added a second author, it repeated the entire list twice.  How does the nested form address the individual object it is displaying?
Were I simply to do a loop, I would identify both the collection, and the individual object reference:
<% **associationobjects**.each do | **association** | %>
  <%= association.object.property =>

associationobjects is the collection, and object is the single.  I could address the single object, by saying association.object.property,
In the nested form, the :document_authors is the collection, but I don't see how the nested form knows that :id belongs to the current document_author.  Therefore, I cannot use that to access the current document_author's individual author, to say what is its name.
<%= document_form.fields_for :document_authors do | author_form, author | %>

I tried to add the single author to the form, but it says "undefined method 'fname' for nil:NilClass".
I tried :author.fname, :document_author.author.fname, and other similar ways, all receiving some variation of "Template::Error (undefined local variable or method "...
<%= document_form.fields_for @document_authors do | author_form | %>

Apologies if the answer for this is simple.  It seems like should be something simple, but I cannot seem to find the answer in any of the documents, or examples of nested forms.

Show your controller action from where the view started rendering

added controller  code above.

I believe I have found a solution:
The form.object is the current object the form is using.
<%= form_with model: @document, local: true, :method => :post do | document_form | %>
...
<%= document_form.fields_for :document_authors do | author_form | %>
    <% author = Author.find(author_form.object.author_id) %>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left">
            <%= author.fname %> <%= author.lname %>
            <%= author_form.hidden_field :id %>
            <%= author_form.hidden_field :document_id %>
            <%= author_form.hidden_field :author_id, value: author.id %>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= author_form.radio_button :is_public, 'true' %></td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= author_form.radio_button :is_public, 'false' %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
...

In this case, the object is a DocumentAuthor, so I can take the author_id, and look up an author, then display the author properties (like fname, lname).

This is a very strange and un-Railsy approach.
Either use nested attributes or a separate controller and AJAX to add/remove authors one by one. What you have create is a strange hybrid that mass updates/creates the nested records in a way that's very bug prone, user unfriendly and atypical.
The big problem here is that each individual @document.document_authors.find_or_create_by( :author_id => author.id ) may fail and that you have to handle that and provide feedback. Also the user should probally have better control than just entiring some search criteria and a bunch of stuff gets created whilly nilly in the wrong controller action.
Nested attributes
You're actually using nested attributes in your model but it all falls apart after that.
The nested attributes way would be to just have the documents controller create/update the nested records when updating the parent.
class DocumentsController < ApplicationRecord

  # GET /documents/new
  # The new method should ONLY render forms and not create anything
  def new
    @document = Document.new
    @authors = Author.all
    5.times do 
      @document.document_authors.new
    end
  end

  # POST /documents
  # This is where creating records should happen!
  def create
    @document = Document.new(document_params)
    if @document.save
      redirect_to @document
    else
      @authors = Author.all
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def document_params
    params.require(:document)
          .permit(
            :foo, :bar,
            document_authors_attributes: [
              :author_id, :public
            ]
          )
  end
end

For simplicty lets ignore whatever attempt you have at an seach function or whatever it is and just create the typical form for a nested record:
<%= form_with(model: @document) |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :document_authors do |ff| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :author_id %>
      <%= ff.collection_select :author_id, @authors, :id, :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :public %>
      <%= ff.checkbox :public %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

You do not need or want all those hidden inputs and that cruft. fields_for handles creating the inputs for the id and the setter in the model handles creating the nested records so you do not need or want to loop though the params with that wonky loop.
Nested attributes is not always the correct solution for every problem and it sometimes results in a better UX and code to create/update/delete the nested records separately.
Progressive enhancement
What you're kind of touching on but failing at is creating a seperate controller to handle the document authors (aka attributions) without the use of nested attributes.
If you want to go down that route start by CRUD'ing the records like you normally would with a nested resouce:
resources :documents do
  resources :document_authors
end

class DocumentAuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_document

  # Typically you wont actually have or need this action as 
  # it's rended on the "parent page"
  # GET /documents/1/document_authors/new
  def new
    @document_author = @document.document_authors.new
    @authors = Author.all
  end


  # POST /documents
  # This is where creating records should happen!
  def create
    @document_author = @document.document_authors.new(document_author_params)
    if @document_author.save
      redirect_to @document
    else
      @authors = Author.all
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def set_document
    @document = Document.find(params[:document_id])
  end

  def document_params
    params.require(:document_author)
          .permit(
            :author_id, :public
          )
  end
end

This approach doesn't actually make that much sense from a user experience perspective until you use Turbo to asyncronously submit the form to create each document author without leaving the page.
And if I have guessed correctly that you have some sort of search and then the user can select authors and add them this is what you should be looking into.
This is really an entire topic on itself though.
